# Mysqli data not getting from database

Tags: php

I upgrade server version from php 5 to 7 but in php 7 version i am not getting data from database while using mysqli. I am getting `false` by using `var_dump()`  function.

```
$this->links =  @mysqli_connect(DB_CONNECT, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
$this->result = var_dump(mysqli_query($this->links,$query));
```

What id error i am not found. There is something missing?

Comment: One thing to stop doing is using `@` in your code, if there is an error you should handle it and not just ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

When you upgrade the server from php version 5 to 7 you need to re-install certain things like mbstring, mysqli etc. Please check that those items are installed in your server, if not please install and check again.

Comment: i checked that all the thing and that are installed.

Comment: Ok , did you see any errors while running this code, if not set show error status to ON by using this code.
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

or check the error log in the folder /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: thanks. By applying that in my file i show all the errors and resolved that all.